# Sending AT Commands from Microcontroller

Tags: c, sms, serial-port, avr, at-command

I am in the middle of a project that is going to use a micro-controller to tell a Sierra Wireless Raven XT to send a test message to the appropriate admin when a pump fails. I have the interrupt for the pin change when the pump fails already completed. My problem is getting the modem to send the text message. I am able to send a text message when connected to the modem through putty or hyper-terminal but when I tell the micro-controller to send those same commands I get nothing.

I am using an ATmega88PA and programming in C. To send the commands over serial communication I am using USART. When I connect to the micro-controller through putty and fake a pump fail the message that is output to the terminal is the exact thing that I would need to type in to send the message myself.

Anyone have any ideas as to what might be holding me up?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using a PC for the programming as well

Comment: Is the baud rate set correctly ?

Comment: What are the settings for flow control: HW, SW?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses I have not checked the baud rate. I will do that and let you know if I have any luck.

Comment: Thanks for the tips it turns out the baud rate for the modem was 115.2K and the micro-controller was 9600. Once I got them set everything started working. thanks @JVXR